# How to split a PDF and keep its form fields

Tags: pdf, pdftk, pdfsam

I am trying to split a multi-paged PDF document that contains form fields (check boxes, text boxes). In case it is important to know, the PDF's form fields are initially all blank/empty/un-checked.  I have tried using `pdfsam` and `pdftk`, but the form fields in the split pages do not work, they appear but I am unable to use them.  I can *merge* multiple PDF documents that contain form fields, and the final product has all the form fields, so I think it should be possible to do the reverse.

I read the man page for `pdftk` and searched forums, but I have not located an answer to the question: **How can I split a PDF document that contains multiple pages with form fields AND keep the form fields in the split documents?**